# orphanremoval doesn't delete if add and remove occur without flush

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm just trying to understand how certain parts of Spring Jpa/Hibernate work. As the title says orphanRemoval only seems to work if entities are flushed to database between adding and removing a child entity from a collection and I'm wondering why.

I've got a parent class with a @OneToMany association with a child class

```
@Entity
class Parent {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Getter
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = parent, cascade=ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @Getter
    private Set<Child> children;
    
    public Parent(){
        children = new HashSet<Child>();
    }

    public Child addChild(Child child){
        child.setParent(this);
        children.add(child);
        return child;
    }

    public void removeChild(Child child){
        child.setParent(null);
        children.remove(child);
    }
}

@Entity
class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Getter
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @Setter
    private Parent parent;
}
```

I was testing to get the child to delete when removed from the parent like so (using an @Autowired JPARepository<Parent,Long> and @JpaTest annotation)

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
class PersistTest {
    
    @Autowired ParentRepository repo; // JpaRepository<Parent, Long>
    @Autowired EntityManager em;

    @Test
    public void whenChildRemoved_thenChildDeleted(){
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        Child child = parent.addChild(new Child());
        repo.save(parent);

        em.flush(); // test fails if removed

        parent.removeChild(child);
        repo.saveAndFlush(parent);
        
        assertThat(repo.findById(parent.getId()).get().getChildren()).isEmpty();
        assertThat(em.find(Child.class, child.getId()).isNull();
    }
}
```

If the entity manager is not flushed between adding the child to the parent and removing it then both assertions fail and when looking at the generated sql there is no DELETE statement made. If the EM is flushed then a DELETE is made and the tests pass.

Basically just wondering if anyone could explain why this is the case and if putting the two operations in separate @Transactional methods would have the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect some transactions being finished or created, but in reality they didn't. That is why you see this behavior.

1. `@DataJpaTest` places on every method separate transaction (which will be rolled back anyway by default BTW);
2. That is why you can use `JpaRepository` -- it does not create the transaction itself (in the opposite to `CrudRepository`), but there is underlying one;
3. If `JpaRepository` used `@Transactional(REQUIRED_NEW)`, you'd may remove flush;

Answer to your last question. If you put those operations in the separate `@Transactional` methods, it will work exactly in the same way, because there is underlying transaction in the test created by the `@DataJpaTest` -- hibernate usually flushes at the very end of the method. You'd have to use `@Transactional(REQUIRED_NEW)`.